# Set-RDSessionCollectionConfiguration Connection Broker connects to localhost

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-v3.0, remote-desktop-services

I am running the following command from a PowerShell console on a Windows 8 machine, trying to configure a Server 2012 R2 RDS Connection Broker:

```
Import-Module RemoteDesktop
Set-RDSessionCollectionConfiguration -CollectionName "Example" -CustomRdpProperty "gatewayhostname:s:rdp.example.com" -ConnectionBroker "ep-ts01.ad.example.com"
```

However, even though I am specifying which Connection Broker to use, it *always* tries to connect to `localhost`:

> New-PSSession : [localhost] Connecting to remote server localhost
>   failed with the following error message : The clie cannot connect to
>   the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on
>   the destination is running an is accepting requests. Consult the logs
>   and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the
>   destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the
>   WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze
>   and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more
>   information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

[image]

However, `Get-RDSessionCollection -ConnectionBroker ep-ts01.ad.example.com` works just fine and returns the collections.

It's the same story if I do `Enter-PSSession ep-ts01.ad.example.com` and run it from there. **However** if I run the command *from the server itself* (i.e. not remotely) it works just fine.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is your 2012 machine setup for PSRemoting properly? From an administrator powershell window on your 2012 machine run `Enable-PSRemoting -Force` to be certain the correct services are configured/running and the appropriate firewall rules (if applicable) are enabled.

Comment: @BenFernandes yeah, fairly sure it is. Everything else with PS remote sessions is working fine.

Answer (score 8):

Mark, I had a lot of fun tracking this down for you.  I can totally see where your line of thought is, but you're asking the wrong question.  The question should be "Why can't I establish a 'servermanagerworkflows' session on my machine?"

If you look in the `$enf:systemroot\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\RemoteDesktop` and open the `SessionCollectionProperties.psm1` module and jump to line 383 there's an entry where Microsoft is intentionally trying to create a local session using the `Microsoft.Windows.ServerManagerWorkflows` configuration.  After the session is instantiated the magic happens in the following Try/Catch/Finally blocks.

If you ran `$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName microsoft.windows.servermanagerworkflow` in a PS prompt on it's own, I'm betting you'd get the same error.  To reinforce this, run `Get-PSSessionConfiguration | Select Name` and I'll bet you don't see `microsoft.windows.servermanagerworkflows` as part of the list.  So, next step is to get you the session config you need.

Run `Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Microsoft.Windows.ServerManagerWorkflows` cmdlet and agree to the prompts.  If successful run `Get-PSSessionConfiguration` again and see if the workflows are listed.  If they are, you should be good to go, or at least generate a new set of errors.

Cheers!

Comment: Oh wow. That's deep. I will try this out as soon as I can!